# Translating "machines" and "people"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, technology

What are the Latin words for *machines* and *people*?
I want to use them as names of wireless networks.
I am not sure how accurate Google translate is, but it suggests *machinae* and *populo*.
Are those even close?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you tell a little where you would like to use these words? The context makes a difference, especially for choosing the most suitable forms. Do you want to use the two words separately (if so, how?) or together somehow?

Comment: Separately, as two wireless network names.

Comment: Thank you for the extra details. I gave an answer and edited your question a bit. Feel free to re-edit.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "machines". It's a word with a lot of meanings, and they are not translated the same way in neo-Latin IT vocabulary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Machina* is indeed a good translation for "machine".
In plural it is *machinae*, so this translation is correct.

You have to be careful with the English word "people".
If you refer to a people (where "people" is singular), the Latin word is *populus*.
(The word *populo* is the singular dative or ablative of this word. Such inflected forms are not a good choice here in my opinion.)
If you refer to to humans (where "people" is plural), the Latin word is *homines*.
A single human is *homo*, and the plural is *homines*.
In the context you give *homines* would be a better choice.
If one network is for humans and the other for machines, then *populus* would be too grandiose.

In general, Google Translate is very unreliable with Latin.
If you want to translate single words, I suggest using any of [several online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).
After finding a list possible translations of your English word, I suggest also looking at the translations from Latin to English for each option; this can provide good insight to choosing the most suitable translation.
If you have trouble finding the correct form, you can ask for help here.
We also have [a guide for asking translation questions](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/143/79) at our meta.

**Added from comments:**
If you want to say "**for** people/humans", then it is *hominibus*, and similarly "**for** machines" is *machinis*. In Latin one uses the dative case instead of a preposition here. But when it's used as a name, the context makes the intention clear, so I would say *homines* and *hominibus* work equally well. Just use *machinae/homines* or *machinis/hominibus* without mixing the two options, for consistency.

Comment: For the people translation, I mean to say "for everyone" or "for everyone who isn't a machine." Would I still use *homines"?

Comment: @AdamF, you can say *omnibus*, but that means both "for everyone" and "for everything". I think using the word *homo* is a good choice. If you want to say "**for** people/humans", then it is *hominibus*, and similarly "**for** machines" is *machinis*. In Latin one uses the dative case instead of a preposition here. But when it's used as a name, the context makes the intention clear, so I would say *homines* and *hominibus* work equally fine. Just use *machinae/homines* or *machinis/hominibus* without mixing the two options, for consistency.

Comment: How about _machinis_ (for machines) and _hominibus_ (for people)?

Comment: @Rafael, I suggested the datives in my comment. I'll edit to add the option to my answer, too.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion **:** that instead of choosing a plural noun, perhaps a group noun would work well.

There is only one machine that forms anything like a network in classical Rome and that is the ***War Machine***. There are several well-known units in the army; maniple ("a handful" platoon), ala (a wing, flank). But more machine-like are--

> **Testudo** (literally 'tortoise') a manoeuvre against arrows and slingstones when shields were interlocked above the heads of the
>   soldiers. And they might be using **Aries** (plural **Arietes**) a battering ram.

or, if you could borrow a term from Greek, which Romans often did (*machina* is a Greek word):

> **Phalanx**  a mass of men in heavy armour advancing in a solid block

**...** then your ***'Men'*** would be a group name from civilian life.

> **Civitas** a city-state populated by "cives".
>   **Gens** a clan.

But if you prefer to use plural nouns, my suggestions would be:

> **Viri** ( plural of **vir** ) grown men, not children.
>   **Molae** (plural of **mola** ) mills.